# Using the JPA2 Criteria API to query for a string subset

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I'm upgrading from the Hibernate Criteria API to the JPA2 Criteria API, and am running into the following problem, which I can't seem to resolve.

In the Hibernate Criteria I was using Restrictions.sqlRestriction to check for a particular kind of string subset:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("{alias}.location_key = left((?), length({alias}.location_key))", searchObj.getLocationKey(), Hibernate.STRING));
```

This essentially checks that the first `N` letters of the input string match the location_key which is `N` letters long.  That is the input string `Canada,ON` should be matched by anything like: `Canada`, or `Can` or `C`.

The problem is that JPA2 doesn't allow us to code native sql like that, and I'm not sure how I can achieve something similar without the `left` function (which I think might be mysql specific).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how your query works, but shouldn't you be able to use CriteriaBuilder.substring(Expression, int) instead of LEFT()? I might come with better ideas if you provide the actual SQL that you wish to generate.

Comment: I did include the sql that I want to generate, roughly.  `select ... where location_key = left(("asdfasdf"), length(location_key));` is a more exact version of the query.  Substring doesn't do me much good, because it expects an Expression<String>, not a String.

Comment: `CriteriaBuilder.literal(T)` creates an `Expression<T>`. So basicly: `criteriaQuery.where(cb.equals(cb.substring(cb.literal(string), 0, location_key.length()), location_key));` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I actually got this working yesterday with parameters, but I think that literals are smarted.